# Хочу добавить ещё раз слайдер но он не работает

Tags: javascript, html5

Хочу добавить ещё раз слайдер, но он не работает и не появляются кнопки на втором слайдере. И после добавления второго слайдера перестает работать первый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML -

```
            <div class="slider">
              <!-- Здесь будут отображаться постеры фильмов -->
                <img src="assets/img/horimiya poster.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 1" class="movie-poster">
                <img src="assets/img/Magichbattle.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                <img src="assets/img/Lamborgini.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                <img src="assets/img/bFG5NYfODoVevfIE__daef5ba680f448333805d8445444b400.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                <img src="assets/img/aULWvyGBYqsKGiaN1qfrSKlzPHE.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                <img src="assets/img/661375314418.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                <img src="assets/img/97045.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                <img src="assets/img/img_1563455630_1372_627_it_ends.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                <!-- Добавьте постеры для других фильмов по мере необходимости -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="prev-button"><img src="/assets/img/prev.svg" alt=""></button>
          <button class="next-button"><img src="/assets/img/next.svg" alt=""></button>
          </section>

          <section class="movies" id="movies2">
            <h2 class="heading">Рекомендуем посмотреть</h2>
            <p class="heading-citation">Популярные фильмы и аниме по отзывам</p>
            <!-- Movie Container -->
            <div class="slider-container">
                <div class="slider">
                  <!-- Здесь будут отображаться постеры фильмов -->
                    <img src="assets/img/horimiya poster.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 1" class="movie-poster">
                    <img src="assets/img/Magichbattle.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                    <img src="assets/img/Lamborgini.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                    <img src="assets/img/bFG5NYfODoVevfIE__daef5ba680f448333805d8445444b400.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                    <img src="assets/img/aULWvyGBYqsKGiaN1qfrSKlzPHE.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                    <img src="assets/img/661375314418.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                    <img src="assets/img/97045.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                    <img src="assets/img/img_1563455630_1372_627_it_ends.jpg" alt="Movie Poster 2" class="movie-poster">
                    <!-- Добавьте постеры для других фильмов по мере необходимости -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="prev-button"><img src="/assets/img/prev.svg" alt=""></button>
              <button class="next-button"><img src="/assets/img/next.svg" alt=""></button>
              </section>
```

JavaScript -

```
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev-button');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');

const slider2 = document.querySelector('#movies2 .slider');
const prevButton2 = document.querySelector('#movies2 .prev-button');
const nextButton2 = document.querySelector('#movies2 .next-button');

let currentIndex = 0;
const posterWidth = 207; // Ширина постера

// Рассчитываем максимально возможное смещение
const maxTranslate = (document.querySelectorAll('.slider img').length * posterWidth) - slider.clientWidth;

function updateSlider() {
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${-currentIndex * posterWidth}px)`;
}

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex > 0) {
    currentIndex -= 1;
    updateSlider();
  }
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Проверяем, не превышено ли максимальное смещение
  if (currentIndex * posterWidth < maxTranslate) {
    currentIndex += 1;
    updateSlider();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема с вашим кодом связана с тем, что у вас есть два слайдера с одинаковыми именами переменных (slider, prevButton, и nextButton) и одним и тем же индексом currentIndex, который используется для обоих слайдеров. Это приводит к конфликту и нежелательному поведению при работе с двумя слайдерами.

```
// Для первого слайдера
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev-button');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

// Для второго слайдера
const prevButton2 = document.querySelector('#movies2 .prev-button');
const nextButton2 = document.querySelector('#movies2 .next-button');
const slider2 = document.querySelector('#movies2 .slider');

let currentIndex = 0;
const posterWidth = 207; // Ширина постера

 // Рассчитываем максимально возможное смещение для первого слайдера
const maxTranslate = (document.querySelectorAll('.slider img').length * posterWidth) - slider.clientWidth;

// Рассчитываем максимально возможное смещение для второго слайдера
const maxTranslate2 = (document.querySelectorAll('#movies2 .slider img').length * posterWidth) - slider2.clientWidth;

function updateSlider(sliderElement, currentIndex, maxTranslate) {
  sliderElement.style.transform = `translateX(${-currentIndex * posterWidth}px)`;
}

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex > 0) {
    currentIndex -= 1;
    updateSlider(slider, currentIndex, maxTranslate);
  }
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex * posterWidth < maxTranslate) {
    currentIndex += 1;
    updateSlider(slider, currentIndex, maxTranslate);
  }
});
```

Добавьте аналогичный код для второго слайдера, используя переменные slider2, prevButton2 и nextButton2